# How do I burn the Ubuntu ISO on Mac OS X Lion?

Tags: mount, mac, macosx

I downloaded the Ubuntu 12.04 Desktop iso and I'm trying to burn it to a disc to install onto a Windows Vista Laptop but it keeps giving me an error saying that It couldn't be burned properly because there are "no mountable file systems"

Anybody know what to do to fix this issue?

Comment: @izx I think this is actually a burning problem rather than (as in that question) a mounting problem. The fundamental issue may be the same but this is a question of *how* to burn it and that is a question of *why* it will not mount.

Comment: @EliahKagan: agreed, changed title to be more accurate.

Answer (score 5):

Please note: **This is for OS X Lion users only**

The easiest way to burn an ISO, the file you need to install Ubuntu from a CD, is by using Disk Utility. If you’re using an older version of Mac OS X, you might not have the Disk Utility application. In this case, use Disk Copy.

- Launch 'Disk Utility' (Applications → Utilities → Disk Utility).
- Insert your blank CD/DVD.
- Drag and drop your .iso file to the left pane in Disk Utility. Now both the blank disc and the .iso should be listed.
- Select the .iso file, and click on the 'Burn' button in the toolbar.[image]
- Ensure that the 'Verify burned data' checkbox is ticked (you may need to click on the disclosure triangle to see the checkbox).[image]
- Click 'Burn'. The data will be burned and verified.

Info collected from [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/burn-a-cd-on-mac-osx)

Please note: **This is for OS X Lion users only**, this no longer works the same way on OS X El Capitan. (This note is in case you've updated from Lion. I'll update this when I find the solution if someone else doesn't chime in sooner)

Comment: Please click on answered if it fix your problem.

Answer (score 3):

As masterninja points out, the hybrid iso from Ubuntu is the issue for OSX Lion.  You can create a readable version with the following steps:

Open the problem ISO in disk utility.  This will mount a device, whose name is listed below the iso name on the left sidebar.  It will probably be disk3s0.

Run this command in terminal, replacing `/dev/disk3s0` with `/dev/YOURISONAME` if it does not match the mounted name from disk utility:

```
dd if=/dev/disk3s0 of=./ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64-extracted.iso bs=1m
```

Now you have a Lion compatible iso file to use as you expected to be able to do in the first place.

Thanks to this guy from youtube, I've just transcribed what he related in his video, which walks you through it if you need additional help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ld7UVefOvHo

Comment: Works like a charm. A small correction: /dev/disk3s0 should be /dev/disk3s1 above.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the hybrid iso Ubuntu is putting out lately, here is a better solution for burning an iso from a Mac - ["burn dvd from iso" article](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-create-an-ubuntu-installation-usb-on-the-mac/)

I was getting an error saying there was no mountable filesystem from the iso, but the hint helped eith my problem and others havign the same one. Hope this helps someone!

[Ubuntu forum with problem explanation](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1870261&p=12250695#post12250695)